# Append a attribute in xml using Powershell based on a condition

Tags: windows, powershell

Below is my XML code:

```
<office>
<staff branch=" Culver City" Type="Implementation">
    <employee >
        <Name>Geoff Lyle</Name>
        <function>Consultant</function>
        <age>40</age>
    </employee>

    <employee>
        <Name>Kevin</Name>
        <function>Consultant</function>
        <age>39</age>
    </employee>

    <employee>
        <Name>David</Name>
        <function>Consultant</function>
        <age>22</age>
    </employee>

</staff>
</office>
```

How do I use powershell to append the attribute "fired" to  if the age is above 40. I have tried writing a script as shown below. Can someone please help me with my syntax

```
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load("C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test.xml")

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff/employee")
$node2 = $xml| Select - XML -XPath "//employee[@age]"
foreach($node in $nodes)
{
if($node2 ge 40){
$node.SetAttribute("status", "fired");
}

}

$xml.Save("C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test.xml")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use XPath to filter the XML nodes by the `age` value:

```
$xmlPath = "C:\Users\rparpani\Desktop\test.xml"
$xml = New-Object XML
$xml.Load($xmlPath)

$nodes = $xml.SelectNodes("/office/staff/employee[number(age) >= 40]")
foreach ($node in $nodes) {
  $node.SetAttribute("status", "fired")
}

$xml.Save($xmlPath)
```

---

Your approach would work if you did `if ($node.age -ge 40) { ... }`, but why not filter the nodes with XPath when we retrieve them with XPath anyway.

Comment: Thank you @Tomalak. I just needed help with the syntax. The feedback was very helpful